# Могут ли в листбоксе отображаться и key, value из dictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, словари

У меня есть коллекция dictionary, есть класс MyClass с интовым свойством  `public Dictionary<MyClass, BitmapImage> MyList = new Dictionary<MyClass, BitmapImage>();`
можно ли сделать так, чтобы в листбоксе item'ы были изображения, а в textbox'ах рядом с каждым изображением писалось свойство класса myclass, соответствующее картинке?

Comment: можно. если определить свой IValueConvertor, и указать его xaml в Binding. при этом из IValueConvertor надо возвращать значения, соответствующие полученному параметру.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       <ItemsControl>
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                               Margin="10" 
                               FontSize="18"  
                               Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
                    </TextBlock>

                    <Image DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Height="70"
                           Width="70"
                           Margin="5"
                           Source="{Binding Path=Picture, Converter={StaticResource Converter}, ConverterParameter='Pictures'}"></Image>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>

   public class MyItem
   {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
   }

  class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
   {


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Path.Combine(parameter.ToString(), value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }


  }


  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();
        items.Add(new MyItem() { Name = "Яблоко", Picture = "1.jpg" });
        items.Add(new MyItem() { Name = "Апельсин", Picture = "2.jpg" });
        items.Add(new MyItem() { Name = "Ананас", Picture = "3.jpg" });
        items.Add(new MyItem() { Name = "Авокадо", Picture = "4.jpg" });
        items.Add(new MyItem() { Name = "Банан", Picture = "5.jpg" });

        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = items;

        List.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
    }
}
```

Вот пример

Comment: ConverterParameter='Pictures' -это название папки где хранятся фотки